# Xpath how to merge to xpaths in to different columns to one row

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, vaadin

I need to search in a vaadin table for two strings date and location and when click the row where the two strings are present i made such an xpath

```
.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(), 'PL')]
```

and i want to add another contain

```
[contains(text(),'2012-12-12')]
```

---

Here is the code

```
 <tbody>
<tr class="v-table-row" style="">
<tr class="v-table-row-odd" style="">
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 316px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 316px;">NY</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 301px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 301px;">2012-07-10</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 602px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 602px;">fhfhf</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="v-table-row v-selected" style="">
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 316px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 316px;">PL</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 301px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 301px;">2012-07-15</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 602px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 602px;">holiday in weekend test</div>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="v-table-row-odd" style="">
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 316px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 316px;">PL</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 301px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 301px;">2012-07-24</div>
</td>
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 602px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 602px;">istotny test raportu</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please, show us the HTML code of the incriminated row.

Comment: Vaadin Table lazy loads rows by default so it's possible that the cell containing the text is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath `and` operation, like so:

```
.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(), 'PL') and contains(text(),'2012-12-12')]
```

You should also be able to express this as:

```
.//div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(), 'PL')][contains(text(),'2012-12-12')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you can try

```
//div[contains(text(), 'PL') and contains(text(), '2012-12-12')]
```